# destroy jquery ui accordion

Tags: jquery, user-interface

how can I destroy a jquery ui accordion if I don not have li elements inside? The scenario would be I have inside of my accordion li elements which user on click can remove. In case if user has been removing all the existing elements the accordion should be destroyed.

html

```
<div id="catalog">
<h4 id="my_id" ><a href="#"></a></h4>       
<div>
<ul class="ul_class">
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="li_id1">element_1
<span id="add" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus" style="float:right"></span>
</li>
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="li_id2">element_1
<span id="add" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus" style="float:right"></span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
jQuery("span#add").live("click", function(){
    html = html.replace('<span style="float:right" id="add" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus">','<span style="float:right" id="remove" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-minus">');
    var param =  $(this).parent().closest('li').attr("id");

    jQuery(this).parent().animate(
            {
                'margin-left':'1000px'
            },1000,
            function(){
                var ul_class = $(this).parent().attr('class');
                $(this).slideUp('fast');              
                $("ul."+ ul_class + "_clone").append('<li id="'+ param +'">' + html + '</li>');
                $(this).remove();

            }
            );
});
```

Comment: Could post some code please?

Comment: The code would need to be added relative to your panel removal script, can you please include that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( ! $('#myAccordion').find('li').length ) {
    $('#myAccordion').accordion('destroy');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tuneup, Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

To destroy a jQuery UI widget, select the element it was initialized on, then call the plugin with the parameter "destroy".

```
$("#accordion").accordion("destroy");
```